# Joomla 1.7 to 3, users and k2 items

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, upgrade, migration, joomla-1.7

I need to update a site from Joomla 1.7.3 to J3.3. Am looking for best way to do this? Joomla manager>update does not find any updates. Online guides are quite vague on how exactly to manually update 1.7 to 2.5 or 3.

Would it rather be best to just build from ground up in J3.3, then import all 1.7 users and k2 items? 
Please advise on a tool for exporting/importing J users from 1.7.3 to 3.x
Also a tool for exporting k2 items/comments (images are not a problem, I could do these separately)

Tx

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to go first to 2.5 and then to 3.0. How to do this manually was already suggested in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019708/joomla-1-7-5-to-2-5-migration-when-not-showing-any-updates-about-2-5

Joomla doc has also an upgrade guide: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Upgrading_from_an_existing_version

Comment: Thanks for the advise.. its actually been a lot of trial and error to get this working. Your suggestion to follow the Joomla doc instructions helped me upgrade Joomla 1.7 to 2.5. It was impossible, no matter how many different tutorials I followed, to get 2.5 to 3. Thanks :)

Comment: @Aida, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool I have come accross for this is the [SP Transfer](http://cyend.com/extensions/extensions/components/91-sp-transfer) from SP Cyend

This allows you to create a new install, get it running with appropriate template and components and then pull data accross table by table if you want.

Use it on most of our migrations, rock solid.

What I would recommend is updating as many of your key components to their latest version possible, just after you have backed up the whole site of course!

Comment: Going from 1.7 to 2.5 to 3 doesn't require a migration tool actually.

Comment: No but if you want to be selective about what information you are keeping.  Also from a purist view jumping those versions through the upgrade process is not something I would recommend.

Comment: I actually found this site on my own and used SP Tranfer very successfully, to import my articles and K2 items/cats into a brand new version of J3. I'll upvote you when I can :)